# Save database results in Dictionary from a function in Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, dictionary

I'm trying to build a dictionary to use later on in my code. For example I want to generate the dictionary at boot and want to overwrite it an hour later.

To do so, I've written the following code:

```
var database   = require('mysql');
var sleep      = require('sleep');
var config     = require('./config.json');
var list       = [];

function getValues(callback){
    var con = database.createConnection(config.database.connection);
    con.connect();
    var query = "SELECT * FROM MODELS WHERE STATUS = 'Active'";
    con.query(query, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        callback(result);
    });
    con.end();
}
list = getValues();
console.log(list);

while(true){
    list.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log(item.name);
    }).
    sleep.sleep(config.general.interval);
    list = getValues();
    console.log(list);
}
```

The result is that `list` remains `undefined`, for example before the while-loop console.log echos: `undefined` and in the while-loop I get the following stacktrace:

```
/test.js:20
    list.forEach(function(item) {
         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nduijvelshoff/Development/Node.js/DataHandler/test.js:20:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Where do I have to do something different? I tried to look it up and came found out that .query for example is async, but can't find how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `callback` which you defined in `getValues` function

Use it as below

```
var database = require('mysql')
var sleep = require('sleep')
var config = require('./config.json')
var list = []

function getValues (callback) {
  var con = database.createConnection(config.database.connection)
  con.connect()
  var query = 'SELECT * FROM MODELS WHERE STATUS = \'Active\''
  con.query(query, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err
    // list object is set here
    list = result;
    callback(result)
  })
  con.end()
}
// this will set list object
getValues()

setInterval(function(){
  //Overwrite logic for list
},config.general.interval)
```

Comment: Using this method I'm creating everything inside my `getValues` function and how do I update the `list` afterwards?

Comment: Please check updated answer, you can use `setInterval` and set updation login here to overwrite list with new values

Comment: Two things happend now:
1. console.log results in: `[ ]`
2. the following stacktrace afterwards:
`/Parser.js:80
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
...`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it, using the [gist](https://gist.github.com/kumatch/5234434) of [Yosuke Kumakura](https://github.com/kumatch).

Long story short; my complete script needed to be changed.